# Problems using FaceBookSDK in an iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am having a hard time trying to do something with FaceBookSDK in an iOS app.

In Xcode I created a New Project, Single View Application (Deployment target: 7.1).

For start, I just want to have a button that post something to Facebook when tapped.
Similar to what happens when tapping the “Post Status Update” button in the *HelloFacebookSample* app.
I copied some code I think is needed from *HelloFacebookSample* provided with the FacebookSDK (Version 3.16.1).

Here is the code in my app:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    UIButton *fbButton;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    fbButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 150.0, 120.0, 50.0)];
    [fbButton setTitle:@"FB" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fbButton setTitleColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [fbButton.titleLabel setFont:[fbButton.titleLabel.font fontWithSize:58.0]];
    [fbButton addTarget:self action:@selector(fbButtonHandler) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:fbButton];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)fbButtonHandler
{
    NSLog(@"fbButtonHandler CALLED !!!!");
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com/ios"];

    FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] initWithLink:urlToShare
                                                                   name:@"Hello Facebook"
                                                                caption:nil
                                                            description:@"The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration."
                                                                picture:nil];

    if (![FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
        NSLog(@"NO canPresentShareDialogWithParams !!!!");
        return;
    }

    FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                                                     clientState:nil
                                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                             if (error) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                             } else {
                                                                 NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                             }
                                                         }];
    if (!appCall)
        NSLog(@"NO appCall !!!!");
}


@end
```

But when running it, nothing is posted and I always get this message:

```
Oops, Something Went Wrong
There was a problem posting your status. We’ve logged the error and will look into it.
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748202/ios-failure-to-post-on-facebook-no-errors-logged

Comment: I guess the problem is, with the session. I didn't see you have created/open a session anywhere. Try this thread step-by-step, configure facebook SDK and relevant stuff. This thread invites facebook friends. If this works, means you have configured things correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495462/presentrequestsdialogmodallywithsession-does-not-work-but-gives-good-result/16654666#16654666

Comment: Thanks I will take a look then.
But where is this session created/open in the HelloFacebookSample app example? This may well be what I missed.

Comment: You don't need an open session (or any session at all) to use the share dialogs as offered by the SDK. You do need to add things like your app id and app name in your app's plist - see the prerequisites for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

Comment: Yes I finally made it work by adding the app on the Facebook developer site. This is the part I was totally missing before.